Rename mounted home directory
I have the following situation, where I have a folder /new_home, and a mount in etc/fstab:
/new_home /home none bind 0 0
So that means that /home does exist, and is a mount point, and /new_home is a directory that contains the actual files.
Now I would like to get rid of the mount and rename /new_home to /home.
The problem is, I cannot unmount or move /home because I am afraid that might crash the system / GUI.
Is that possible?

First of all, make sure you can log in as root. (This account doesn't rely on /home.) Not sudo but a real login.
Then you can proceed. It's probably best not to use the GUI here:

Comment out the line in /etc/fstab
Try unmounting /home but if that fails because something's using it just reboot instead and login as root (without the GUI)
Move (rename) /home to /old_home
Move /new_home to /home
Reboot

If all goes wrong then log in as root and revert.

Comment out the home mount. Reboot and login as root. Make your changes. Reboot again and login as an ordinary user with /home containing the desired files.
